# php debugging in eclipse: xdebug watch expressions are <uninitialized>

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I am using xDebug in eclipse to debug my php application. Everything works fine but I cannot watch expressions. No matter what expression I enter, they evaluate to `<Uninitialized>`. What could be the reason?

Comment: What sort of expressions do you enter? What's in your remote debugging log?

Answer (score 1):

I've often read on the internet that updating to a newer version of xdebug solves the problem.
You can download one [here](http://xdebug.org/download.php).
Of course you'll have to update your php.ini too.
Unfortunately it didn't solve it for me, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: Yes, updating xdebug has solved similar problems for me in the past.